# STEP7 MICROWIN PLC Ladder Diagram

Tags: control-system, diagram, plc, automation, ladder

[image: Which one is right?]

I draw like the first figure in the program, but when I save the program it automatically becomes the second shape. Do the two mean the same thing?

Comment: Please undelete your other question "PLC Ladder Diagram Number of Networks" to which I took the time to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.

The ladder diagram is a representation of the logic in an electrical diagram format. In relay logic the two circuits are equivalent.

See if you can convert it to STL (statement list) and understand the logic being executed by the PLC. Doing this will help you appreciate the sequence of instructions and their execution order by the controller.